# Unexpected behaviour when splitting file by byte-size

Tags: bash, split, byte, naming

Assume that a `file` containing multi-line alphanumeric strings is split into small subfiles by byte-size. The subfiles are to be labeled numerically.

```
$ split -d -b 100 file subfile
```

The resulting subfiles are labeled as expected until subfile 89, but then change their labeling pattern. Interestingly, the labeling pattern changes again at subfile 9899!

```
$ ls
file
subfile00
subfile01
...
subfile89
subfile9000  # sic!
subfile9001
...
subfile9899
subfile990000  # sic!
subfile990001
...
```

This pattern seems odd to me. Is there a way to split file `file` by byte-size and receive subfiles that are labelled continuously from 0 to x, where x = total split number?

**EDIT 1**:

```
$ split --version
split (GNU coreutils) 8.25
```

Comment: Are you ok to have files with leading `0` i.e. `file001`, `file002`, `file100`?

Comment: @Inian Yes, I'd be okay with that. Thus, I will try out your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GNU` split by default controls the suffix length to be added to the file using the `-a` option (`2` default value). You can over-ride with the max digits depending upon the number of split files using this `-a` option

```
-a, --suffix-length=N
     use suffixes of length N (default 2)
```

E.g. If you think, your split files could vary from 1-100, you can run the `split` command with `3` as suffix length.

```
$ split -a 3 -d -b 100 file subfile
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The naming pattern works properly if leading zeros are enforced.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl: Happy to help!